# Java Jersery: How to handle multiple Queries Parameters for a REST URL with UriInfo

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I have implemented a rest Query as shown below:

```
@Path("list")
@GET
public List<Todo> getTodos(@Context UriInfo uriInfo){
  MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParameters = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
  List<String> parameterList = queryParameters.get(assignee.name);   //Output -> name1,name2 parameterList --  size -1
  String parameter = queryParameters.getFirst(assignee.name); //Output -> name1,name2
  .
  .
  .
}
```

How do I handle when multiple parameters

```
http://localhost:9090/hello-todo/api/v1/todo/list?assignee.name={name1,name2}
```

**Here instead of two strings, I am getting it as one single string. How should I handle it, should I split the parameter String by comma (,).?**

When

Currently it is able to handle these endpoints. The Rest URL's are

```
http://localhost:9090/hello-todo/api/v1/todo/list

http://localhost:9090/hello-todo/api/v1/todo/list?status=CRITICAL

http://localhost:9090/hello-todo/api/v1/todo/list?status=MAJOR

http://localhost:9090/hello-todo/api/v1/todo/list?status={criticality}&todo.completion.status=completed

http://localhost:9090/hello-todo/api/v1/todo/list?status={criticality}&todo.completion.status=completed&todo.title={title}

http://localhost:9090/hello-todo/api/v1/todo/list?status={criticality}&todo.completion.status=completed&todo.title={title}&todo.startDate={startDate}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `queryParameters.get(assignee.name);` to return a list, you can include the parameter more than once in the URL

`http://localhost:9090/hello-todo/api/v1/todo/list?assignee.name=name1&assignee.name=name2`

Or you can continue to have a single parameter (`list?assignee.name=name1,name2`) and split on `,`, but you have to write the code to do that, and consider what to do when one of your names has a `,` character in it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. when a parameter has ',' character in it. Should we ask the end user to pass it as '\,'  for escaping the character. Is that the standard way of handling such cases?

Comment: There is no standard for storing a list in an URL parameter AFAIK, so you'll have to design and document it yourself